# Rational Team Concert - Can you merge local files to current repository?

Tags: rational-team-concert

Normally a repository in Rational Team Concert compares itself to a base Stream to know what you have added or removed since you've started working.

a side-project started (*before we started using RTC*), and has now finished. It has the same folder/file structure as the structure within my local repository.

Is there some way to create a patch between this local folder/file and my current RTC repository so I don't need to manually compare the two file-by-file? I'm hoping RTC would automatically handle files where one or the other (*but not both*) have changed - but collisions would need to be viewed so I can make sure they are handled correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If you have delivered all your change sets in your repo workspace, then you can import the files into the existing project. Then, when you check in those changes, you should be able to see any changes. One tip to avoid excessive changes, is to use the Eclipse or RAD source format (CTRL+SHIFT+F). Use that to standardize the original code first. Then import, and format the new code. Check in the code, and see if you have any changes. It should only show you changes that actually have real differences (not just whitespace).